# How to pass a GLfloat array through function in C++?

Tags: arrays

I'm trying to pass a GLfloat type array through a function but the new variable only take the 1st value of the array (0.5f in this case), what am i doing wrong?

My Code:

```
void main()
{
// some code
GLfloat vertices[] = {
        // Positions          // Colors           // Texture Coords
         0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, // Top Right
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, // Bottom Right
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, // Bottom Left
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f  // Top Left 
    };
passingArray(vertices);
}
void passingArray(GLfloat anotherVertices[])
{
// this anotherVertices only take 1st value of the vertices array
}
```

Comment: I suggest you should learn how pointers and arrays work in C++ before embarking on trying to use OpenGL with it. It doesn't work like java or C#. Don't run before you can walk.

Comment: How do you know that it only gets the first value?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas I tried to print all the values of the array and it could only print the 1st value. I also check the sizeof(anotherVertices) and its value is 4 which means it contains only 1 GLfloat value.